# Using exclusive or in an if statement, C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, xor

I searched around the site and Google, but was unable to find quite what I was looking for.  I think it's pretty simple, but I'm fairly new to C# so I'm having some troubles with this one.

Basically, I have an if statement to test the selection of Radio buttons I have, which is triggered on the click of a button.  By default, I don't have any selected, and my program will notify me if I forget to select one, with a MessageBox.  So essentially, you can't do anything until you have a selection made.

Up until now, I only had 3 radio buttons, but today I have added one more, and a bunch more code associated with the new one, including a new function.

I'm still trying to figure out what is the most memory efficient way to test for the radioButton.Check  Now, is that with temporary variables, or with this if statement I have?

```
if (pRKButton.Checked != true ^ hexButton.Checked != true ^ binaryButton.Checked != true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose a method of encryption.");
            return null;
        }
        else....//More Goes Here
```

My main question is this:  Why when I add one more argument to the if statement, using exclusive or, like so;

```
if (pRKButton.Checked != true ^ hexButton.Checked != true ^ binaryButton.Checked != true ^ md5Button.Checked != true)
```

The program doesn't register me clicking **ANY** of the radio buttons.

At this point I'm considering making a listbox to hold all the values and select the choice, as the list will grow.  But I'm super curious about the reasoning behind not being able to use exclusive or with more than 3 arguments.  I'm not mathematician, by any degree, but I'd love to learn more.

Comment: "Memory efficient"? You're checking three radio buttons once, you do not need to worry about memory!

Comment: I don't think you know what the `^` operator does actually.

Comment: The Exclusive or works with two boolean and return a boolean. You can't use XOR with more than two bools. Or actually, if you write more than two, you are doing exclusive or with the first result.

Comment: Why are you even bothering with the check? Default to the most common you find your users selecting and dont worry about it. Its extra logic you dont need to worry about.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, just wanted to know for the future, thanks for explaining what is more efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before I get to the main part of the question, I want to point out that you don't actually need to use XOR here. When you have radio buttons only zero or one can be selected. When you select one, the others in the same group automatically become deselected. So you can use `||` to test if at least one is selected.

```
if (pRKButton.Checked || hexButton.Checked || binaryButton.Checked)
{
   // At least one (i.e. exactly one) is checked.
}
else
{
   // None checked.
}
```

To answer the main part of your question, your code fails because when you have one button selected you get `false ^ true ^ true` (noting that you are testing if the buttons are *unchecked*). The result of this is false. But when you have four variables you instead have `false ^ true ^ true ^ true` which is true.

`XOR` does not mean "only one is true" as you seem to think. `A XOR B XOR C` is true if an odd number of A, B, C are true. This is not the same as "exactly one" because it is true if all three of A, B and C are true.

See the following [truth table](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A+XOR+B+XOR+C) to understand the behaviour of chained XOR with three inputs:

[image: A XOR B XOR C]

Comment: Note that this is the opposite of what you're testing in your example, plast1K, so either swap your code blocks or reverse what you test.

Comment: Using three ^ arguments based off 

    var1 != true ^ var2 != true ^ var3 != true

Worked, where using 4 arguments doesn't.  I'll try using pipes, thanks :]

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative post, this table clarified things immensely; I can see why it worked with the 3 variables, and why it will not with 4.

I definitely misunderstood how ^ worked, and when it should be used.

Comment: @Abe Miessler: If the control is a radio button, exclusivity is handled by the UI, right?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mark Byer's good information about radio button functionality, you might be concerned that your code will get smelly with a very long if statement.

Try using LINQ to simplify:

```
container.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any<RadioButton>(r => r.Checked);
```

Will be true or false based on any radio button being checked.

Comment: Thank you Reacher, I'll review this.  I was indeed worried about that, and asked about efficiency in the first post, I've heard mixed things about LINQ; mostly pertinent to efficiency, as a matter of fact.

What's more efficient, an obnoxiously long statement, or a slightly shorter one using LINQ?

Comment: This is a fair question. Most of the LINQ benchmarking I've seen were against LINQ to SQL or ORM scenarios. Informally, I have seen some impact on efficiency for my own scenarios, but they vary by <100ms for very large collections. Having said that, I think improved readability is a lot cleaner and more maintainable in general.